# Issue with Visual Basic - Me.Hide() or Me.Close()

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I'm totally new at this, so my question are suppose to me very simple..

I have made a very simple login form.
When password and username is right, i want to close password form and load main_form..

But I don't know exactly how to write this..

So far I have this when you click at the login button in the first form:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If username.Text = "user" And password.Text = "pass" Then
        Me.Hide()
        dreamware_main.Show()

    Else
        pass.Text = "Wrong user name or password!"
    End If
End Sub
```

It works great the first time I run the project, but the second time, it wont run project and gives me the error that my application is still running..

I'm guessing it's because of the Me.Hide() that just hides my login_form, but never closes it... that's why it wont run the second time,

I've tried with Me.Close() instead, and when I do that it will run the project the second time, but that just closes all my forms, and I don't want that..

How can I close the first form, without closing dreamware_main?

Comment: I am not by a computer, but VB.net does have an option to close the program when all of the Forms are closed not just the startup Form. Look in the project properties.

Answer (score 4):

As Mark Hall pointed out, in Project --> Properties, change the "Shutdown mode" to "When last form closes":
[image]

This will allow you to Close() the login form without causing the whole application to exit.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest you reconsider your login concept. Open the main form and display login form on top of that. Then the default would work for you, which is "when startup form closes".

This is nice one.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I think it should be `Me.Hide()` and then `Me.Close()` - to cover some layout issues, which I don't remember off top of my head. If those are not bothering you, it's usually `Me.Close()`.

Regarding your question - see Idle_Mind's answer for a possible solution.

I would like to suggest you reconsider your login concept. Open the main form and display login form on top of that. Then the default would work for you, which is "when startup form closes".

From personal experience, it is a more extensible development pattern, as you may want to allow some guest access to your application later, or allow log off and log in under a different account.

Or, with single sign-on, you will authenticate with a Windows account, so no need to show a login form.

Another side note - users generally like to see where they are about to log in.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
Me.Hide
Unload Me
```

Answer (score -1):

try `Me.Hide` instead of `Me.Hide()`

Comment: @felipsmartins A code-only answer might not be a good one, but it's still an answer. I would recommend you this post about the LQPRQ: [You're doing it wrong: A plea for sanity in the Low Quality Posts queue](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue)